# Secondary property extent

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate

I'm in the UK and the OS paperwork showing boundaries of my house details both a primary and secondary property extent.

The primary property extent is the expected boundary of my house. The secondary property extent is both at the front of my house (up to middle of the road), and the back of my garden (covering the neighbouring lake's land).

What is the secondary property extent? Does it mean I have rights or responsibilities for this area?

Thank you

Comment: What does the Land Registry show, and are there any easements that may be relevant?

Comment: I've had a look through the documents I have at hand and can't find anything relevent. The map showing the primary/secondary has a red square for the primary property extent and blue squares showing secondary property extents. That's all I know.

Comment: You should ask the land registry, they ought to know what they mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article at:

[Private Rights of Way](https://www.landregistry-titledeeds.co.uk/frequently-asked-questions/information/examples-private-rights-of-way.asp)

Specifically for this case it shows these two drawings:

[image: Images from https://www.landregistry-titledeeds.co.uk/frequently-asked-questions/information/examples-private-rights-of-way.asp]

To quote the text from that page:

The right of way exists along the northern border of the first property, and the southern border of the second property. The latter shows more detail of the right of way, together with the Title Number of another property affected by it. The rights of way are indicated by letters along the border, where the right of way exists. Note how the red edging of the properties occurs inside the black OS borders.

> The Title Registers for these properties, between them, complete the
> description and location of this right of way. It is evident from an
> examination of the Plans and Registers that a far better picture of
> the right of way can be gleaned from reading both Registers and Plans
> together. It is for this reason that we provide title documents for
> both properties with our search.

From what you have said in your question, it appears to me that this section covers your case and the RED part is your property and the BLUE areas indicate where you have a right-of-way to pass over it without permission from that parcel's owner.